# Overloaded method value rowList52 error in scala

Tags: java, scala, jdbc

I am new to Scala and my scala code is using '`import acolyte.jdbc.RowLists`' structure as below with total 52 values.

```
val ROWLIST = RowLists.rowList52(
    classOf[String] -> "ABC",
    classOf[String] -> "BCD",
    classOf[String] -> "PQR",
    classOf[String] -> "STU",
    classOf[String] -> "LMS",....)
```

If I add more values now, it gives me error as below,

```
    [error] overloaded method value rowList52 with alternatives:
[error]   [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, AG, AH, AI, AJ, AK, AL, AM, AN, AO, AP, AQ, AR, AS, AT, AU, AV, AW, AX, AY, AZ](x$1: acolyte.jdbc.Column[A], x$2: acolyte.jdbc.Column[B], x$3: acolyte.jdbc.Column[C], x$4: acolyte.jdbc.Column[D], x$5: acolyte.jdbc.Column[E], x$6: acolyte.jdbc.Column[F], x$7: acolyte.jdbc.Column[G], x$8: acolyte.jdbc.Column[H], x$9: acolyte.jdbc.Column[I], x$10: acolyte.jdbc.Column[J], x$11: acolyte.jdbc.Column[K], x$12: acolyte.jdbc.Column[L], x$13: acolyte.jdbc.Column[M], x$14: acolyte.jdbc.Column[N], x$15: acolyte.jdbc.Column[O], x$16: acolyte.jdbc.Column[P], x$17: acolyte.jdbc.Column[Q], x$18: acolyte.jdbc.Column[R], x$19: acolyte.jdbc.Column[S], x$20: acolyte.jdbc.Column[T], x$21: acolyte.jdbc.Column[U], x$22: acolyte.jdbc.Column[V], x$23: acolyte.jdbc.Column[W], x$24: acolyte.jdbc.Column[X], x$25: acolyte.jdbc.Column[Y], x$26: acolyte.jdbc.Column[Z], x$27: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AA], x$28: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AB], x$29: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AC], x$30: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AD], x$31: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AE], x$32: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AF], x$33: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AG], x$34: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AH], x$35: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AI], x$36: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AJ], x$37: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AK], x$38: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AL], x$39: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AM], x$40: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AN], x$41: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AO], x$42: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AP], x$43: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AQ], x$44: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AR], x$45: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AS], x$46: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AT], x$47: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AU], x$48: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AV], x$49: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AW], x$50: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AX], x$51: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AY], x$52: acolyte.jdbc.Column[AZ])acolyte.jdbc.RowList52.Impl[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,AL,AM,AN,AO,AP,AQ,AR,AS,AT,AU,AV,AW,AX,AY,AZ] <and>
[error]   [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, AG, AH, AI, AJ, AK, AL, AM, AN, AO, AP, AQ, AR, AS, AT, AU, AV, AW, AX, AY, AZ](x$1: Class[A], x$2: Class[B], x$3: Class[C], x$4: Class[D], x$5: Class[E], x$6: Class[F], x$7: Class[G], x$8: Class[H], x$9: Class[I], x$10: Class[J], x$11: Class[K], x$12: Class[L], x$13: Class[M], x$14: Class[N], x$15: Class[O], x$16: Class[P], x$17: Class[Q], x$18: Class[R], x$19: Class[S], x$20: Class[T], x$21: Class[U], x$22: Class[V], x$23: Class[W], x$24: Class[X], x$25: Class[Y], x$26: Class[Z], x$27: Class[AA], x$28: Class[AB], x$29: Class[AC], x$30: Class[AD], x$31: Class[AE], x$32: Class[AF], x$33: Class[AG], x$34: Class[AH], x$35: Class[AI], x$36: Class[AJ], x$37: Class[AK], x$38: Class[AL], x$39: Class[AM], x$40: Class[AN], x$41: Class[AO], x$42: Class[AP], x$43: Class[AQ], x$44: Class[AR], x$45: Class[AS], x$46: Class[AT], x$47: Class[AU], x$48: Class[AV], x$49: Class[AW], x$50: Class[AX], x$51: Class[AY], x$52: Class[AZ])acolyte.jdbc.RowList52.Impl[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,AL,AM,AN,AO,AP,AQ,AR,AS,AT,AU,AV,AW,AX,AY,AZ]
[error]  cannot be applied to ((Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[Integer], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String), (Class[String], String))
[error]   val ROWLIST = RowLists.rowList52(
[error]
```

**Question** - I wish to add more values to it. Is there a way to accomplish it?